# Spring logback log class level filtering

Tags: spring, logging, logback

I'm trying to filter logback output by class.
It seems not to work.

Am I Wrong ?

```
logging.level.net.myapp=ERROR
logging.level.net.myapp.package.MyClass=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.scheduling=ERROR
logging.level.root=ERROR
```

MyClass sample

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void sampleMethod() {
        LOG.debug("Debug message");
        LOG.error("Error message"); //see only that one
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: I expect to see debug logs for MyClass only, the rest of myapp only error logs.. I do not see debug logs for MyClass

Comment: Could you post a bit about `MyClass` class and its use of `Logger`?

Comment: Edited message. It's a whole sample I've described here, my real classes are complex, and for this specific problemm not very useful to be posted here